# Will debugging slow down JavaScript applications on mobile platform?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile

This is a generic question regarding performance of JavaScript applications. Mobile applications running on JavaScript frameworks need a lot of optimization. If a JavaScript application has a lot of debuggers, will it lead to slower performance?  How will performance differ for the following code snippets between browser and mobile if my debugger/firebug is disabled?

**Code without debuggers**

```
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

**Code with debuggers**

```
var r = confirm("Lets test debugger performace");
if (r == true) {
debugger;
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
debugger;
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

Comment: Theoretically it might as the number of commands to be executed have been increased. But practically have few hundreds of debugger shouldn't create much impact.

Comment: Code that real people will be using (not just test code) should never have `debugger;` statements in it.  They should always be removed when you are done testing.  As you learn to use a debugger, you can set breakpoints on individual lines of code for debugging purposes without actually modifying your source code.

Comment: Agreed, while it probably won't have any noticeable impact (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) and linked ECMAScript standards from there), it is bad practice to have so many `debugger` statements go into production.  It is fairly simple to remove them via mass find/replace. I've only really found them useful when setting a breakpoint via dev tools is difficult (e.g. proxy debugging a mobile device).

Comment: This question came up cause of an issue I faced recently in one of my application. There were around 20 debuggers in 5 Javascript files. The performance was slow on low end Android devices and Windows 8 devices. After removing debuggers it saved almost 2 seconds.